# try except with more than one situation

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, try-except, except

I have a set of columns including data. I need sum of 3 largest components. The problem is that in some columns I have just 2 or 1 data. So I need use try and except to keep my code alive. Also in columns with 2 data I need sum of them and with 1 data I need that.
How should I modify this code?
Thanks in advance.

```
for i in df.index.unique():
    dff=df.loc[i]
    colum=dff['CENSUS2010POP']
    try:
        ss=sum(colum.nlargest(3))
    except:
        ss=sum(colum.nlargest(2))
    except:
        ss=sum(colum.nlargest(1))
```

Comment: You may want to provide a real sample of data that throws the error, and the entire traceback of the error.

Answer (score 2):

You could just clamp to the size of the column to make sure you don't try to access too many elements

```
ss = sum(colum.nlargest(min(3, colum.size)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I learned something new. The problem didn't solve also with this. I finally find out that for columns with 1 component nlargest method makes problem. I solved the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The other proposed solution is better, but if you're curious about the specific question you asked, this is how you would use multiple try-excepts:

```
for i in df.index.unique():
    dff=df.loc[i]
    colum=dff['CENSUS2010POP']
    try:
        ss=sum(colum.nlargest(3))
    except:
        try:
            ss=sum(colum.nlargest(2))
        except:
            ss=sum(colum.nlargest(1))
```